# XML Calabash MacOS gives SLF4J Error when running any xpl

Tags: calabash, xproc

I'm trying to install XML Calabash 1.3.2 on MacOS in order to use XPROC. I installed XML Calabash using brew:

```
brew install calabash
```

When I enter the following in the terminal:

```
calabash --version
```

It shows me the correct output of version 1.3.2 But, when I try to run any xpl file, I receive the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I tried to install SLF4J using MacPorts, but no success.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you get nothing but those messages as the result of running a pipeline? Or do you get the pipeline's output as well?

Comment: I get nothing but this output.

Comment: Is that a pipeline you know to work? Is that just an installation problem on that particular Mac or are you new to XProc? I, for instance, after installing the latest XML Calabash version from GitHub on Windows get the same messages (already when doing `--version`) but the pipeline output is displayed after those messages if I run a pipeline.

Comment: If I understand https://github.com/ndw/xmlcalabash1/issues/324 right, then the issue is kind of known and you need to make sure you put additional logger jars on the classpath. So probably installing SLF4J doesn't suffice, when then calling calabash you need to make sure the installed jars are on the class path (`-cp` option of `java`).

Comment: I tried adding them to the class path but same result. With Morgana I had no such issues.

Comment: I don't think Norm, the creator of XML Calabash reads here, but I guess asking a support issue on GitHub will give you are more informed answer as to what goes wrong and how to fix it.